# If graph isomorphism yields a polynomial time algorihtm

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, graph-isomorphism

Greeting I'm studying computing theory and are trying to grasp the concept of complexity classes.

If graph isomorphism (suspected NPI) turns out to have polynomial time solution. What possible implication it has or what can we possibly deduce?

Thanks for any explanation

Answer (score 2):

Nothing bad is known to happen if Graph Isomorphism can be solved in polynomial time; see [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19962/consequences-of-a-quasi-polynomial-time-algorithm-for-the-graph-isomorphism-prob) on cstheory. On the other hand, problems in the complexity class [GI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem#Complexity_class_GI) will all have polynomial time algorithms.